# Redirección 301 de dominio1 a dominio2 en el mismo espacio web

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo el dominio1 y el dominio2, **pero ambos están apuntando al mismo espacio web**.

Si cada dominio tuviera su propio espacio, entonces cada uno tendría su propio fichero .htaccess con sus respectivas configuraciones. Pero al tener dos dominios apuntando a un mismo espacio web se me escapa un poco de las manos.

¿Cómo puedo hacer una redirección 301 del dominio1 al dominio2 en esta situación?

Aclaro que una vez llame al dominio2 necesitaré un htaccess específico para el domino2; que reconozca las URL amigables, el SSL, etc. Y que además, no se ejecute la redirección 301 en caso de entrar directamente al dominio2.

Espero haberme hecho entender. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Después de unas pruebas creo que quizás era más simple de lo que parecía.

He modificado el .htaccess de esta manera:

**Antes:**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio_destino/$1 [R,L]
```

**Después:**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio_destino/$1 [L,R=301]
```

De este modo, me apunta correctamente del dominio1 al dominio2, "**dominio_destino**".

Además, en caso de colocar el dominio2 directamente en el navegador sin especificar el protocolo https, este lo establece automáticamente.

De todas maneras, me gustaría saber vuestras opiniones. Estoy aprendiendo y es importante saber que esté haciendo las cosas bien. Pretendo llevar a cabo una estrategia SEO en donde el dominio1 es un dominio EMD y el dominio2 un dominio de MARCA para darle un empujón en las SERPS.

Gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: Agrego la siguiente herramienta, para quien pueda ayudarle, con la cual he podido comprobar los resultados y parece funcionar correctamente:

http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/


La herramienta detecta el tipo de redirección en este caso devolviendo el valor "Type of redirect: 301 Moved Permanently"

Gracias!